# Metodo Option en llamada

Tags: angular, typescript

Como elimino las el metodo option en la llamadas realizadas con Angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo ts

```
 public get(url:string , token : string , parms : any){

let headers : HttpHeaders  = new HttpHeaders ({"access-token" : token});
let parmx   : HttpParams   = new HttpParams();
parms.forEach(function (val : any) {
 parmx                     =  parmx.set(val.key, val.value);
});

return this.http.get(url , { headers: headers , params: parmx , reportProgress:true});
```

}

```
public post(url:string , token: string , data : any) : Observable<any> {
let headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders ({"access-token" : token , "Content-Type":"application/json"});
return this.http.post(url, data, { headers : headers , reportProgress:true });
```

}

Comment: Eso es normal se llama `preflight request`. Puedes informarte más acerca de eso https://www.baeldung.com/cs/cors-preflight-requests

Comment: Muchas gracias ! es que estaba revisando mi servidor tambien tiene un costo de procesamiento, por ello buscaba eliminar esa llamada previa.